# Function that will find a prime number in an array of numbers

Tags: c, function

The function takes three elements of the array , and of those three elements it finds the first prime number and puts it on first position,then it moves to the next element and finds a prime number between those three elements,if none of those numbers are prime , there is no transforming. The last two numbers stay untouched. Here is my code , having some trouble with it.Would like some help.
To make it clearer , first three items lets say A[i] A[i+1] A[i+2] The prime number is put on A[i]

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#define ITEMS 10



int Transform(int *num,int k,int j,int x){

    while(j!=ITEMS-3){


    if(num[j]%2==0)

    break;

    if(num[j]%2!=0)

    num[x]=num[j];

    j++;

    k++;

    x++;

    if(num[k]%2==0)

    break;

    if(num[k]%2!=0)

    num[x]=num[k];

    j++;

    k++;

    x++;

    if(num[x]%2==0)

    break;

    if(num[x]%2!=0)

    num[x]=num[x];

    j++;

    k++;

    x++;
}

}

        int main(void){


        int num[ITEMS];

        int i,j,k,x,pom;

        i=0;

        k=i+1;

        j=i+2;

        x=i;

        for(i=0;i<ITEMS;i++){

        printf("Enter the array : /n");

        scanf("%d",num[i]);

        pom=Transform(num,j,k,x);


        printf("%d",pom);

    }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you say you have some trouble, can you be more specific? I.e. does it compile? Does it run without crashing? How does it deviate from your expectations?

Comment: @cnicutar After i type in the first element , it simply crashes

Answer (score 0):

Given `int num[ITEMS]` you probably meant:

```
scanf("%d", &num[i]);
            ^
```

If you omit that you trick `scanf` into thinking that whatever is in `num[i]` is an address.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the first prime of every three numbers in an array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i += 3)
    for(int j = i; j < i+3; j++)
        if(isPrime(nums(j)))
        {
            primes[i/3] = nums[j];
            break;
        }
```

The code is something like this, but I have not tested it.